# Restrict HTTP access to single page with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have this `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Can I force all HTTP access attempts to serve a specific page (e.g. `/https-required.html`) while processing HTTPS access normally?

Here is an example of the behaviour I expect, with some variation tolerated (for instance, if `/https-required.html` can *only* be served over HTTP, that's acceptable):

```
http://www.ex.com/                     => http://www.ex.com/https-required.html
http://www.ex.com/valid-page.html      => http://www.ex.com/https-required.html
http://www.ex.com/invalid-page.html    => http://www.ex.com/https-required.html
http://www.ex.com/https-required.html  => http://www.ex.com/https-required.html

https://www.ex.com/                    => https://www.ex.com/
https://www.ex.com/valid-page.html     => https://www.ex.com/valid-page.html
https://www.ex.com/invalid-page.html   => https://www.ex.com/404.html
https://www.ex.com/https-required.html => https://www.ex.com/https-required.html
```

---

I wish to restrict the whole site to HTTPS but for that I must necessarily account for HTTP access attempts. I think I can disable HTTP completely, with something like

```
SSLRequireSSL
```

but that would yield a miserable experience for accidental HTTP access. The more common solution to this problem is to simply redirect `http://` to `https://` with something like

```
Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com
```

or

```
RewriteCondition %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but I am specifically looking to avoid this redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule !^https-required\.html$ /https-required.html [L,NC,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```